# Using System.Net.IpAddress as complex type in oData model but serializing/deserializing as string in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, odata, aspnet-api-versioning

I have a model I'm using in a `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` Web API that has `System.Net.IpAddress` as a property. I need the OData controller to serialize/deserialize the IP address as a string.

Here is an example of the model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public IPAddress Ipaddress { get; set;}
}
```

And a simple example of generating the Edm Model for it:

```
public class EdmModel
{
    public IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

        var ip = builder.ComplexType<IPAddress>();
        //ip.Ignore(i => i.Address);
        ip.Ignore(i => i.AddressFamily);
        ip.Ignore(i => i.IsIPv4MappedToIPv6);
        ip.Ignore(i => i.IsIPv6LinkLocal);
        ip.Ignore(i => i.IsIPv6Multicast);
        ip.Ignore(i => i.IsIPv6Teredo);
        ip.Ignore(i => i.IsIPv6UniqueLocal);
        ip.Ignore(i => i.ScopeId);

        var model = builder.EntitySet<TestModel>("TestModel").EntityType;
        model.ComplexProperty(p => p.Ipaddress).IsRequired();

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
}
```

The controller returns a json representation of the IP address structure but I need it as a string.

I've tried to write and inject a json converter but the OData doesn't use it. I also need to figure out how to show the OData XML schema to use a string instead of the IP address complex type.

Here's the json converter (that works on it's own just not through the OData API):

```
public class IpAddressJsonConverter : JsonConverter<IPAddress>
{
    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public override IPAddress Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return IPAddress.Parse(reader.GetString());
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, IPAddress value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to include your converter in the JsonSerializerOptions somehow, but I have no idea how that should be done  in OData.

Comment: Could https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/customize-formatter help?

Comment: Adding a json converter either to the host or as an attribute doesn't work because odata just bypasses it. You have to let the odata edm know the ipaddress is a string somehow.

Comment: @AlekseiPetrov I looked into that but couldn't get it to work. There aren't a lot of examples of how to use it. I'm sure it could work but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use a system type like this, just use a `string` or custom class you made. Much safer.